# Invariant and periodic measures of the random dynamical system on the circle generated by $d\theta_t=dW_t$

Tags: ergodic-theory, brownian-motion

Here, I am considering one of the simplest random dynamical systems that one can consider, and yet I realise that I do not know the answer to one of the most basic questions that one can ask about it!

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all continuous functions $\omega:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\omega(0)=0$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ satisfying the requirement that the map $\omega \mapsto \omega(t)$ is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. (It is known that $\mathcal{F}$ coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.)

For any $\omega \in \Omega$, define $\theta\omega \in \Omega$ by $\theta\omega(t)=\omega(t+1)-\omega(1)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, let $R_\alpha:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ denote the anticlockwise rotation through angle $2\pi\alpha$. Define the function

$\begin{align}
\Theta \, : \, \Omega \times \mathbb{S}^1 \ &\to \ \Omega \times \mathbb{S}^1 \\
\Theta(\omega,x) \ &= \ (\theta\omega,R_{\omega(1)}(x)).
\end{align}$

> > Find the set of all $\Theta$-invariant probability measures $\mu$ on $(\Omega \times \mathbb{S}^1, \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1))$ with the property that
> >     $$ \mu(E \times \mathbb{S}^1) = \mathbb{P}_W(E) \ \ \ \forall E \in \mathcal{F} $$
> >     where $\mathbb{P}_W$ denotes the unique probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ under which the stochastic processes $(\omega \mapsto \omega(t))_{t \geq 0}$ and $(\omega \mapsto \omega(-t))_{t \geq 0}$ are independent Wiener processes.

One obvious measure with the desired properties is $\mathbb{P}_W \otimes \lambda$, where $\lambda$ denotes the (normalised) Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$. But I don't know if there are any others.

Comment: The measure $\mathbf P_W$ is not shift-invariant; is it possible that your formulation is not really what you wanted to ask? Could you maybe reformulate it in a less formal way?

Comment: @RW: I think the idea is that you take (1) a point; and (2) a 2-sided Brownian motion going through 0. The action is to shift the BM 1 unit to the left; subtract a constant so as to ensure that ensure that the shifted BM goes through 0 (I think this is missing in the Q) and keep track of the shifts that have been made.

Comment: @Julian: It looks to me as though your $\theta$ should be $\theta(\omega)(t)=\omega(t+1)-\omega(1)$, right?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas and RW: I'm sorry about that, yes $\theta$ is meant to be exactly as described by Anthony, *not* as I've currently got it. Thank you for pointing this out for me! I'm changing it now.

Comment: A more probabilistic proof of this result can be obtained as follows: Your process is Brownian motion on $\mathbb{S}^1$, which can be, for example, realized as $Z_t=W_t\;\mathrm{mod}\;2\pi$. From this, it is easy to obtain an explicit expression of the Markov transition semigroup of $Z$, which is then seen to be strong Feller and topologically irreducible at any time $t>0$ and to admit the Lebesgue measure on the circle as invariant measure. Therefore, Doob's theorem yields the uniqueness of the invariant measure. Conclude with Arnold, Theorem 1.7.2.

Comment: @julian I think your argument will only yield uniqueness of those $\mathbb{P}_W$-projecting $\Theta$-invariant measures for which the $\Omega$-fibrewise disintegration is measurable with respect to the past sub-$\sigma$-algebra (and hence, by time-reversal, likewise for the future sub-$\sigma$-algebra). In other words - to use what I think is the language of the Arnold textbook - your argument shows uniqueness of the *Markov invariant measure* of the RDS, but does not exclude the possibility of other invariant measures of the RDS that are not Markov invariant measures.

Comment: This is a fair point. My argument doesn't give you that and actually can not prove this. In fact, it is well-known that the RDS corresponding to the SDE $dX_t=\sin(X_t)dW_t^1+\cos(X_t)dW_t^2$ ($W^1$ and $W^2$ independent Wiener processes) has *two* invariant measures, whose disintegrations are measurable wrt. the past and the future of the driving noise, respectively. Since $X$ is also Brownian motion on the circle, standard probability theory can not tell the two systems apart. But note that the invariant measure depending on the future is unphysical since it requires clairvoyant ...

Comment: ... knowledge of the future. This is roughly the point made by Hairer when introducing the notion of Stochastic Dynamical Systems, which seem to be more natural in studying stochastic evolutions. But that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think there's a very direct argument to show that if $\mathbb P_W\times\lambda$ is ergodic then it's the unique invariant measure projecting onto $\mathbb P_W$. Let $\bar\Omega=\Omega\times S^1$ and define a rotation $R_s\colon \bar\Omega\to\bar\Omega$ by $(\omega,t)\mapsto (\omega,s+t\bmod 1)$. Notice that if $\mu$ is an invariant measure, then so is $R_s^*\mu$. If $\mu$ is an invariant measure projecting to $\mathbb P_W$, then $\int_{S^1}R_s^*\mu=\mathbb P_W\times\lambda$. Since $\mathbb P_W\times \lambda$ is ergodic, you deduce $R_s^*\mu=\mathbb P_W\times\lambda$ for almost every $s$.

Comment: Wow, this is wonderful. It seems to me that this argument should completely generalise, and provide a much shorter proof of the theorem that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: For future readers: the proof that $\mathbb{P}_W \times \lambda$ is ergodic can be found within my answer further below. [I should probably have said that the way I extend the ergodicity of $\mathbb{P}_W|_{\mathcal{F}_0^\infty} \times \lambda$ to the ergodicity of $\mathbb{P}_W \times \lambda$ is adapted from Theorem 1.7.2(i) of Ludwig Arnold's monograph *Random Dynamical Systems* (Springer, 1998).]

Comment: I think the natural level of generalization is a group extension - or possibly a quotient group extension of a dynamical system. A key property here is that the convolution of Haar measure with anything is Haar measure.

Comment: Yes, group extensions are what I had in mind. Specifically, we should have: **Theorem.** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, let $\theta:\Omega\to\Omega$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-preserving measurable map, let $X$ be an abelian compact metrisable topological group with Haar measure $\lambda$, and let $R:\Omega\to X$ be a measurable function. Define the skew product $\Theta:(\omega,x)\mapsto(\theta(\omega),R(\omega)x)$. If $\mathbb{P}\times\lambda$ is $\Theta$-ergodic, then it is the only $\Theta$-invariant measure whose projection onto $\Omega$ coincides with $\mathbb{P}$.

Answer (score 0):

So your question can be rephrased this way: $\theta$ maps $\Omega$ to itself and preserves the measure $\mathbb P_W$. You are then asking about a skew product extension of $\theta$: $\bar\theta:\Omega\times S^1\to \Omega\times S^1$ given by $\bar \theta(\omega,t)=(\theta(\omega),t+\omega(1))$. In fact, this is a group extension of $\theta$. Write $\bar\Omega$ for $\Omega\times S^1$ and let $\pi\colon\bar\Omega\to\Omega$ map $(\omega,t)$ to $\omega$.

You're looking for the $\bar\theta$-invariant measures on $\bar\Omega$ that project to $\mathbb P_W$. Any measure $\mu$ of that type can be disintegrated into fibre measures over each $\omega$. Write $\mu_\omega$ for the (probability) measure on $S^1$ over the point $\omega$. A general result for group extensions shows that $\mu_\omega$ is a translation of Haar measure on a closed subgroup of the circle (i.e. the circle itself or the $n$th roots of unity for some $n$); by ergodicity of $\theta$ it's the same subgroup for each $\omega$. It just remains to check that the situation where the fibre measures are supported on a discrete subgroup can't arise. You can reduce to the case $n=1$ by working modulo $1/n$ instead of modulo 1, so we really just need to show that $\mu$ cannot be supported on the graph of some function $f\colon \Omega\to S^1$.

If this were the case, we would have $f(\theta(\omega))=f(\omega)+\omega(1)$, so that $g(\omega)=\omega(1)$ would be a couboundary. Hence it suffices to show that the map $g\colon \Omega\to S^1$ given by $g(\omega)=\omega(1)$ is not a coboundary. It's not, but I don't have a nice argument in mind right now. I'll get back to you soon (or maybe you'll find this argument yourself). By the way, this condition is equivalent to ergodicity of $\mathbb P_W\times \lambda$ under $\bar\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I'm not so familiar with group extensions, I started trying to find on Google the general result that you cited - and as it turns out, I found another result that pretty much directly answers my question. So I've decided to include that answer as well. (But I haven't managed yet to find the result that you cited - do you know off-hand of any references?)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer; it is based on Proposition 3.10 of [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:1400855160).

**Claim:** $\mathbb{P}_W \otimes \lambda$ is the *only* $\Theta$-invariant probability measure whose projection onto $\Omega$ is $\mathbb{P}_W$.

I start by proving that $\mathbb{P}_W \otimes \lambda$ is $\Theta$-ergodic (which I was already able to prove before - however, there may well exist a nicer proof than mine):

*Proof that $\mathbb{P}_W \otimes \lambda$ is ergodic.* Let $P$ be the Markov transition function describing the dynamics on $\mathbb{S}^1$; that is,
$$P(x,A) \ := \ \mathbb{P}_{N(0,1)}(\alpha \in \mathbb{R}:R_\alpha(x)\in A)$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^1$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$. Obviously $\lambda$ is a stationary distribution for $P$. We also clearly have that for every $\lambda$-positive measure set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$, $P(x,A)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^1$; therefore, $\lambda$ must be the *only* stationary distribution, and so in particular, must be ergodic.

Consequently, $\Theta$ is an ergodic transformation of the probability space $(\Omega \times \mathbb{S}^1,\mathcal{F}_0^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1),\left.\mathbb{P}_W\right|_{\mathcal{F}_0^\infty} \otimes \lambda)$, where $\mathcal{F}_0^\infty:=\sigma(\omega \mapsto \omega(t):t \geq 0)$. (For a justification of this, see e.g. Theorem 143(ii) of [my notes](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jmn07/Ergodic_Theory_for_Semigroups_of_Markov_Kernels.pdf), which is a slight generalisation of Theorem 3.1 of [here](http://jlc.jst.go.jp/JST.Journalarchive/kyotoms1969/19.83?from=Google) or Theorem I.2.1 of [here](http://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-9175-3).)

Now suppose for a contradiction that $\Theta$ is not an ergodic transformation of the full probability space $(\Omega \times \mathbb{S}^1,\mathcal{F} \otimes \Sigma, \mathbb{P}_W \otimes \lambda)$; so we can write $\mathbb{P}_W$ as a non-trivial convex combination of two distinct $\Theta$-invariant probability measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. Since $\left.\mathbb{P}_W\right|_{\mathcal{F}_0^\infty} \otimes \lambda$ *is* ergodic under $\Theta$, we have that
$$ \left.\mu_1\right|_{\mathcal{F}_0^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)} \ = \ \left.\mu_2\right|_{\mathcal{F}_0^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)} \ = \ \left.\mathbb{P}_W\right|_{\mathcal{F}_0^\infty} \otimes \lambda. $$
Now let $\mathcal{F}_T^\infty:=\sigma(\omega \mapsto \omega(t):t \geq T)$ for each $T \in \mathbb{R}$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it is clear that $\theta^n$ is $(\mathcal{F}_0^\infty,\mathcal{F}_{-n}^\infty)$-measurable and that the map $\omega \mapsto \omega(n)$ is $(\mathcal{F}_0^\infty,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable. So then, $\Theta^n\colon(\omega,x) \mapsto (\theta^n\omega,R_{\omega(n)}(x))\,$ is $\,(\mathcal{F}_0^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1),\mathcal{F}_{-n}^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1))$-measurable. So, for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_{-n}^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$, we have that
$$ \mu_1(A) = \mu_1(\Theta^{-n}(A)) = \mu_2(\Theta^{-n}(A)) = \mu_2(A). $$
So then, since $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ agree on $\mathcal{F}_{-n}^\infty \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ agree on the whole of $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$, contradicting our assumption that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are distinct measures. **QED**

With this, to prove the Claim, we just apply the following theorem (adapted from Proposition 3.10 of the book by Furstenberg that I cited at the top of this answer):

**Theorem.** *Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a standard measurable space, let $\theta:\Omega \to \Omega$ be a measurable map, let $X$ be a compact metrisable abelian topological group with $\lambda$ denoting the Haar measure, and let $R:\Omega \to X$ be a measurable function. Define the function $\Theta:\Omega \times X \to \Omega \times X$ by $\Theta(\omega,x)=(\theta\omega,R(\omega)x)$. For any $\theta$-invariant probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, if $\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda$ is $\Theta$-ergodic, then the* only *$\Theta$-invariant probability measure $\mu$ satisfying $\mu(E \times X)=\mathbb{P}(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{F}$ is $\,\mu=\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda$.*

Now Furstenberg actually assumes that $\theta$ is uniquely ergodic and concludes that $\Theta$ is uniquely ergodic. Nonetheless, the proof given directly yields the theorem as I have given it above. I will now write the proof of the theorem:

*Proof of Theorem.* Fix a compact metrisable topology on $\Omega$ whose Borel $\sigma$-algebra coincides with $\mathcal{F}$. For any probability measure $\mu$ on $\Omega \times X$ and any point $(\omega,x) \in \Omega \times X$, we will say that $(\omega,x)$ is *$\mu$-generic* if
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\Theta^n(\omega,x)) \ \underset{N \to \infty}{\to} \ \int_{\Omega \times X} f(\tilde{\omega},\tilde{x}) \, \mu(d(\tilde{\omega},\tilde{x})) \hspace{4mm} \forall \, f \in C(\Omega \times X,\mathbb{R}). $$

**Observation 1** [c.f. Proposition 3.7 of Furstenberg]**:** *For any $\Theta$-ergodic probability measure $\mu$, $\mu$-almost every point in $\Omega \times X$ is $\mu$-generic.* [It seems to me that the continuity of the dynamical system in Proposition 3.7 is not needed; all that matters is that the relevant class of functions on the phase space admits a countable uniformly dense subset.]

To see this: Let $\mu$ be any $\Theta$-ergodic probability measure, and let $S$ be a countable dense subset of $C(\Omega \times X,\mathbb{R})$. By Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, the set $Y \subset \Omega \times X$ of points $\mathbf{x}$ with the property that
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\Theta^n(\mathbf{x})) \ \underset{N \to \infty}{\to} \ \int_{\Omega \times X} f(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) \, \mu(d\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) \hspace{4mm} \forall \, f \in S $$
is a $\mu$-full measure set. We now show that every point in $Y$ is $\mu$-generic. Fix any $\mathbf{x} \in Y$, any $f \in C(\Omega \times X,\mathbb{R})$ and any $\varepsilon>0$. Pick any $f' \in S$ with $|f(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})-f'(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})|<\varepsilon$ for all $\tilde{\mathbf{x}} \in \Omega \times X$. We have that
$$ \limsup_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\Theta^n(\mathbf{x})) \leq \left(\limsup_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f'(\Theta^n(\mathbf{x})) \right) + \varepsilon = \int_{\Omega \times X} f'(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) \, \mu(d\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) + \varepsilon \leq \int_{\Omega \times X} f(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) \, \mu(d\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) + 2\varepsilon $$
and likewise
$$ \liminf_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\Theta^n(\mathbf{x})) \ \geq \ \int_{\Omega \times X} f(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) \, \mu(d\tilde{\mathbf{x}}) - 2\varepsilon. $$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have the desired statement.

**Observation 2:** *For any $\omega \in \Omega$ and any probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$, if there exists $y \in X$ such that $(\omega,y)$ is $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-generic then $(\omega,x)$ is $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-generic for all $x \in X$.*

To see this: Fix $\omega \in \Omega$ and $x,y \in X$, and suppose that $(\omega,y)$ is $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-generic. Fix any $f \in C(\Omega \times X,\mathbb{R})$, and define $f' \in C(\Omega \times X,\mathbb{R})$ by $f'(\tilde{\omega},\tilde{x})=f(\tilde{\omega},\tilde{x}y^{-1}x)$. We have

$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\Theta^n(\omega,x)) \ = \ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f'(\Theta^n(\omega,y)) \
&\underset{N \to \infty}{\to} \ \int_\Omega \int_X f'(\tilde{\omega},\tilde{x}) \, \lambda(d\tilde{x}) \, \mathbb{P}(d\tilde{\omega}) \\
&= \ \int_\Omega \int_X f(\tilde{\omega},\tilde{x}) \, \lambda(d\tilde{x}) \, \mathbb{P}(d\tilde{\omega})
\end{align*}$

as required.

**Completing the proof:** Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a $\theta$-invariant probability measure such that $\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda$ is $\Theta$-ergodic, and suppose for a contradiction that the conclusion of the theorem fails. By observation 1, $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-almost every point is $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-generic; and therefore, by observation 2, there exists a $\mathbb{P}$-full set $\Omega' \subset \Omega$ such that every point in $\Omega' \times X$ is $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-generic. Now since the conclusion of the theorem fails, there exists a $\Theta$-ergodic probability measure $\mu$ distinct from $\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda$ such that $\mu(E \times X)=\mathbb{P}(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{F}$. By observation 1, there exists a $\mu$-full set $Y \subset \Omega \times X$ such that every point in $Y$ is $\mu$-generic. Obviously $Y$ is not contained in $(\Omega \setminus \Omega') \times X$ (otherwise $Y$ would be $\mu$-null), and therefore it follows that there exist points in $\Omega \times X$ that are *both* $(\mathbb{P} \otimes \lambda)$-generic *and* $\mu$-generic. However, this is not possible, since a probability measure on $\Omega \times X$ is uniquely determined by the values of the integrals that it assigns to all the members of $C(\Omega \times X,\mathbb{R})$. **QED**

Obviously applying the theorem to my example completes the proof of the Claim.

Comment: To be utterly precise, irreducibility of the semigroup doesn't yet give you unique for the invariant measure. You need in addition strong Feller at some positive time. A famous counterexample would be the Ising model in dimension $d\geq 2$ above the critical temperature.

Comment: @julian This is indeed true; "irreducibility" here can be taken to mean e.g. "for each $\lambda$-positive measure open set $U$, $P(x,U)>0$ for all $x$". In my proof, I used the much stronger fact that for every $\lambda$-positive measure *Borel* set $A$, $P(x,A)>0$ for all $x$. This *does* imply that $\lambda$ is the unique stationary measure, without requiring additional assumptions such as the strong Feller property.